# Why does xdg-open block on command-line?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian

My system is Debian 12. I try to use `xdg-open` to open an image file, yet it blocks when the image file is opened. The image viewer has to be closed before `xdg-open` returns.

While many people state that `xdg-open` returns immediately in their environment. I wonder whether this is a configuration or distribution issue. If possible, is there any option to let xdg-open detach and return immediately. I searched the `xdg-open` document yet didn't find anything.

Comment: I use xdg-open in Ubuntu without blocking, so I think it's configuration issue. As it's a shell script you can debug by `sh -x /usr/bin/xdg-open imagefile` in order to undersand why it's blocking.

Comment: @Philippe that's a good idea to debug the script. On my Debian system, for a png file, xdg-open landed on `display-im6.q16` which is part of the imagemagick package. The call of the display script will block. After removing imagemagick, the png file will land on `feh`, but again, it blocks. How about your output?

Comment: I just tested on Debian, I see `+ DE=gnome3`. When I run `xdg-open --version`, I got `xdg-open 1.1.3`. I cannot see `display-im6.q16` or `feh` in `xdg-open` script.

Comment: Thanks! My xdg-open version is the same as yours. Both `display` and `feh` are external packages: they register themselves to be able to handle png files. Now I tend to think the issue is due to the X-environment: I didn't install any X env, so xdg-open is using the generic path to execute the open request.

Comment: @Philippe I use GUI, but just didn't install X-Env packages like Gnome or KDE, so xdg-open will fall into the X-Generic path in their processing. `xdg-open` returns immediately in your case is because it calls `gio`: gio detaches and return immediately. When at X-Generic, xdg-open calls the program directly, and it blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdg-open` is just a wrapper to open a file with an application that can handle it.

As such, it doesn't make any guarantees about whether it will block or return immediately: this is up to the delegated application (so if `xdg-open` ends up calling `display-im6.q16`, then it is `display-im6.q16` that is blocking (or not).

Of course things are a bit more complicated.
E.g. if i run `xdg-open file.jpg` then i also get `display-im6.q16`, but without blocking. Why? Because i have *also* installed the `exo-utils`, so `xdg-open` does not call `display-im6.q16` directly, but instead calls `exo-open` which (for whatever reasons) does not block.

Now, i haven't found any documentation that guarantees that `exo-open` will *not* block.
If you want to `xdg-open` to return immediately, just background it:

```bash
xdg-open myfile &
```

If you don't want to remember having to do this, you could also create an excutable file `/usr/local/bin/xdg-open` which (depending on your `PATH`) should take precedence over the system installed `/usr/bin/xdg-open`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/xdg-open "$@" &
```

Or install some lightweight (at least I think it is lightweight) middleware like `exo-utils`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads-up on `exo-utils`: it is such a nice light-weight program launcher. Since `exo-utils` is part of the XFCE framework, one needs to define `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` as `XFCE` in order to trick xdg-open to use it.

Answer (score -1):

try to install/reinstall the package `xdg-utils`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xdg-utils
```

If this one doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-utils
```

If that doesn't work, try to update your packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```